# Kivy Error at Wheel Installation Process under Windows7 64 at .dist-info (Python 2.7)

Tags: python, kivy, python-wheel

When running install command, following the instructions at paragraph "Nightly Wheel Installation" and after upgrading the pip tool from command line I get an error (see message below):

Install command used:

```
cd  ~\Downloads 
python -m pip install nightly-Kivy-1.9.2.dev0-cp27-co26m-win_amd64.whl --upgrade
```

The console confirms start of the install but displays an error message:

```
"%s .dist-info directory not found"
```

I see a directory allocated under c:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\Kivy-1.9.2.dev0.dist-info.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: try uninstall manually and install then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for guidance. Was able to reinstall it by use of a GIThub project named: "KivyInstaller", which removed older Windows Kivy versions and successfully downloaded and installed the new 1.9.2 dev version using a preconfigured .bat script.